# why cannot install tensorflow-gpu on Ubuntu16.04 cuda8.0 system

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, ubuntu-16.04

It confused me much time when I import tensorflow on my system in python:
It shows below:

> > > import tensorflow
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
> > >           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> > >         File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
> > >           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> > >         File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > >           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
> > >         File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
> > >           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > >         File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
> > >           return _load(spec)
> > >       ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/hanwen/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-gpu/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: because the tensorflow binary you are trying to run expects CUDA 9.0.  CUDA 8.0 will not work with that, nor will CUDA 9.1 or 9.2: `ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`  It requires CUDA 9.0

Comment: I have uninstalled CUDA 8.0 and installed Cuda9.0 as well as it's compatible cudnn. It also shows the same problem.